# angular 5 and 6 switch case

Tags: angular, switch-statement, angular5, angular6

hey guys what seems to be the problem here? I'm using switch case in the view. But it doesn't seems to be working.

```
template: `
  <div [ngSwitch]="color">
    <div *ngSwitchCase"'red'">You picked red</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase"'green'">you picked green</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase"'blue'">You picked blue</div>
  </div>

`,
styles: [`

`]
})
```

This is the component file.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    public color = "red";
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the image attached]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing = signs:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'red'">You picked red</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'green'">you picked green</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="'blue'">You picked blue</div>
```

Comment: Great :) Make sure to accept the answer if it was satisfying.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to accept the answer I tried to vote but it wouldn't allow me to

Comment: @OmarMohmedAbdelhady There is a check mark under the voting thing. If you click on it it will accept the answer.